# How can I call .dll from my python code in linux via mono?

Tags: linux, docker, mono, python-3.6, python.net

I have a docker container with a debian python3.6 base image, on which I'm trying to install mono in order to call a utility .dll ( a.NET Framework assembly that was compiled using visual studio ("release" option)) from my python code. I've installed mono because my python code needs to use pythonnet. When I attempt the call with the following line of code:

```
clr.AddReference(PATH_TO_DLL)
```

Mono crashes with the following stack trace:

```
mono_gdb_render_native_backtraces not supported on this platform, unable to find gdb or lldb
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /opt

# create a virtual environment and add it to PATH so that it is 
applied for all future RUN and CMD calls
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# install msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg2 \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | 
apt-key add - \
    && curl 
   https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools


# Install Mono for pythonnet.
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --yes \
    dirmngr \
    clang \
    gnupg \
    ca-certificates \
    # Dependency for pyodbc.
    unixodbc-dev \
&& apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
&& echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian 
stretch/snapshots/5.20 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono- 
   official-stable.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes \
    mono-devel=5.20\* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV \
# From here on, use virtual env's python.
&& venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \

&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
# Dependency for pythonnet.
&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir pycparser \
&& venv/bin/pip install -U  --no-cache-dir "pythonnet==2.5.1" \
"pythonnet==2.5.1"
```

I can't figure out what's causing this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Lex Li I thought that was made clear by mentioning pythonnet, which is used to call .NET artifacts.

Comment: "Running on Linux/Mono: Unit testing shows that PythonNet will run under Mono, though the Mono runtime is less supported so there still may be problems." from http://pythonnet.github.io/ You might consider working closely with the developers to see whether they can help you out. Tons of open issues on Mono https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mono

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python.Net Issue Tracker](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/984#issuecomment-778786164):

```py
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime

rt = get_coreclr("path/to/your.runtimeconfig.json")
set_runtime(rt)

import clr
```